# Lagrange multipliers method

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am currently doing some exercise on the Lagrange multipliers methods and have come upon some confusion. following my lectures notes is says:

$$L= f(x,y) + \lambda g(x,y) $$

and in some online examples it says:

$$L= f(x,y) - \lambda g(x,y) $$

where $f(x,y)$ is the function to be minimized/maximized and $g(x,y)$ is the constraint.

Which one is correct? many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually it is same,because  we can  consider  signs as a alternatives  of maximize or minimize,so  you can use it without  any problem.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

maybe also  author's definition plays some role as well.so i think there is not  big difference between  $+$  sign ad $-$ sign in  this case

i found you  case
http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~cajones/math2640/notes4.pdf

please see this

Comment: ok thank you very much, your help is much appreciated

Comment: so now you could accept  any of them  if everything is fine.good lucks my friend

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter which one you use, the $\lambda$ you get when solving the system of equations will just be the negative of the other method.

Comment: ok thank you very much, your help is much appreciated